# Switching to polar coordinates in differential equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Hi guys i need to help with this excercises. :)

> If 
>   $$\begin{cases}
> x=r\cos \theta\\
> y=r \sin\theta
> \end{cases}$$
>   prove that the equation:
>   $$x^2\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}+2xy\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x\partial y}+y^2\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial y^2}=0$$
>   is equivalent to 
>   $$r^2\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial \theta^2}=0.$$
>
> OK I´VE TRIED

this could be helpful ? then, what do i make?

I tried of isolate  $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}cos\theta-\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}(\frac{1}{r})sin\theta$$and
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}(\frac{1}{r})cos\theta+\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}sin\theta$$

mm and we know that
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}cos\theta+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}sin\theta$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}=-\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}rsin\theta+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}rcos\theta$$

but I do not get anything.

How can I do to get the result??
help.

Comment: There appears to be an error in the problem statement. As one answer has already shown, the equivalent formula is $r^2\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial r^2}=0$, not $r^2\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial \theta^2}=0.$

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the first differential equation from Cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates, or you can convert the second differential equation from polar coordinates to Cartesian coordinates.
I think the second way is slightly easier.

First, observe that by the product rule,
$$r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left(r \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)
 = r \left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial r} \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}
           + r \frac{\partial}{\partial r}
                \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)\right)
 = r \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} + r^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2},$$

that is,
$$ r^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2}
 = r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left(r \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)
   - r \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}. \tag 1$$

We can convert the right-hand side of this equation to Cartesian coordinates
as follows.

Let $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$. Then for any $u$,

\begin{align}
r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}
&= r\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}
         + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\right) \\
&= r\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \cos\theta
         + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \sin\theta\right) \\
&= x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}.
\end{align}

Apply this formula,
$r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}
 = x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$,
with $r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}$ in place of $u$:

\begin{align}
r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}u\right)
&= x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}u\right)
   + y \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}u\right) \\
&= x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} 
 \left(x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)
   + y \frac{\partial}{\partial y}
 \left(x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)
\end{align}

Working out the various terms,

\begin{align}
x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)
 &= x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + x^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}, \\
x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)
 &= xy \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}, \\
y \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)
 &= xy \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}, \text{ and}\\
y \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)
 &= y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + y^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}.
\end{align}

Therefore

\begin{align}
r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}u\right)
&= x^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
  + 2 xy \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}
  + y^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}
  + x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
&= x^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
  + 2 xy \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}
  + y^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}
  + r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} u,
\end{align}

that is,

$$ r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}u\right)
    -  r \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}
  = x^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
    + 2 xy \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}
    + y^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}. \tag 2$$

Taking Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ together, we find that

$$ r^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2}
  = x^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
    + 2 xy \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}
    + y^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}.$$

This is a little stronger than the fact that was to be proved, but it
certainly does imply that the equations
$x^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
    + 2 xy \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}
    + y^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = 0$
and $r^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2} = 0$ are equivalent.

Comment: ok,, thanks,, :) but why do you say $r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left(r \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)
 = r \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} + r^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2},$

Comment: Product rule for the partial derivative of the product of $r$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}$.

Comment: That's also how $x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right) = x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + x^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ and $y \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right) = y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + y^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}$ later in the derivation.

Comment: OK, I spelled out the use of the product rule for $r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left(r \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)$ a little more explicitly in the answer, but I hope it is clear enough later that $x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)$ and $y \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)$ are evaluated the same way.

Answer (score 0):

In the formula for $\partial z\over\partial\theta$, replace the function $z$ with $\partial z\over\partial x$, then with $\partial z\over\partial y$, and finally with $\partial z\over\partial\theta$. The resulting three equations can be combined to get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a booring exercise to compute the partial derivatives in polar coordinates (below, the steamroller technique). May be one can find a smarter method ?

[image]